# Why is e.preventDefault() a function and not a property

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault

Why was `e.preventDefault()` defined as a function and not as a property, for example `e.preventDeafult = true;`?

Wouldn't there even be advantages of it being a property, since you could set `e.preventDefault = false` if you want the default to happen but another callback has already set it to `true` previously?

Comment: because `preventDefault` involve some logic [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-event-preventdefault%E2%91%A2).

Comment: If it was a boolean, when would it get checked? Would you expect the interpreter engine to constantly be checking all your code it if contains this "special boolean"? That sounds expensive. And if multiple callbacks are fighting to use or not use preventDefault, there's probably a design flaw in the logic.

Comment: @Shilly it could check after the callback has finished executing, or the property could have a getter and a setter.

Comment: "*you could set `e.preventDefault = false`*" - I would see that as a disadvantage.

Comment: @Shilly The boolean flag would be checked just like the internal boolean flag that currently exists: after the event has been dispatched and all handlers have been executed.

Comment: @AlanOmar There is not much logic: "*The `preventDefault()` method steps are to set the canceled flag […]*" which in turn does "*if event’s cancelable attribute value is true and event’s in passive listener flag is unset, then set event’s canceled flag, and do nothing otherwise.*"

Comment: Maybe because it's an *action* you perform, stopping a natural behavior of an event. Also hides the internal workings of the logic behind.